# How to remove 000 while decoding the JSON in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How to remove `000` from epoch time in JSON while parsing in swift ?

```
class Person : Codable {
    var birthdate: Date = Date()
}

var json: String = """
{
    "birthdate": 1627516800000,
}
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//dateFormatter.locale = .current
//dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
//dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"

let people = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
print(people.birthdate)// Prints 53543-12-16 00:00:00 +0000 Incorrect due to extra 000
```

Comment: The extra 000 means the number is not in seconds, but in milliseconds, so use `millisecondsSince1970` instead for the date decoding strategy.

Comment: @Sweeper you are right

Comment: @Amit If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The epoch time is measured in milliseconds, not seconds. So the decoder thinks that there have been `1627516800000` seconds that have passed since January 1st, 1970, instead of `1627516800` seconds, or `1627516800000` *milliseconds*.

The solution is to change your decoding strategy from `.secondsSince1970` to `.millisecondsSince1970`:

```swift
class Person : Codable {
    var birthdate: Date = Date()
}

var json: String = """
{
    "birthdate": 1627516800000,
}
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//dateFormatter.locale = .current
//dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
//dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"

let people = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
print(people.birthdate)
```